# Which FTP backup system works for this scenario?

Tags: backup

We're a company who only has access to a limited amount of diskspace. A total backup of our data is around 300 megabytes.

We would like some kind of system that only uploads files that have changed, in order to save this disk space and use it more efficiently.

Furthermore (optionally), we would love if the system had a feature to decrease the backup intensity as time passes by, again to optimize efficiency. Here's an example of what we had in mind regarding this:

- backup of 1 day ago
- backup of 2 days ago
- backup of 3 days ago
- backup of 4 days ago
- backup of 5 days ago
- backup of 6 days ago
- backup of 7 days ago
- backup of 2 weeks ago
- backup of 4 weeks ago
- backup of 6 weeks ago
- backup of 8 weeks ago
- backup of 10 weeks ago
- backup of 12 weeks ago
- backup of 4 months ago
- backup of 7 months ago

And so on. So in other words, we would like (if possible) a system that starts out with high frequency backups, and then later replaces older backups with new ones, while still keeping some "points" of data back in time.

The operating system of our server is Windows Server 2008.

Comment: Operating system?

Comment: Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your operating system [BackupPC](http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/) might work for you. It

- Gained FTP support in 3.2.0 version
- Can keep X full copies and perform incremental backups over them
- Transfer files very effectively using rsync (if FTP is not actually a must for you)
- Is able to store only one physical copy of the file if the same file is present in multiple places, reducing the disk / tape space needs at your backup server.

[Here is an example](http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/faq/BackupPC.html#what_to_backup_and_when_to_do_it) about full / incremental backups with BackupPC.

Comment: Is there a compiled executable of this program, for Windows Server 2008?

Comment: As long as it works with Windows Perl implementation it should work, though BackupPC is geared towards unixish systems.